# C libcurl force "Content-Type"

Tags: c, libcurl

I have the follwing C code with libcurl to upload a file to my webserver, almost ok the only problem I need the upload to be "Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel" but it gets "Content-Type: application/octet-stream", tried with headers but now luck. In PHP with curl is easy, I just do `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array("importfile" => "@".$file_path . ";type=application/vnd.ms-excel"` and works ok. Any help? Ideas?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res;

  struct curl_httppost *formpost=NULL;
  struct curl_httppost *lastptr=NULL;
  struct curl_slist *headerlist=NULL;
  static const char buf[] = "Expect:";

  curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

  curl_formadd(&formpost, &lastptr, CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "importfile", CURLFORM_FILE, "document.csv", CURLFORM_END);
  curl_formadd(&formpost, &lastptr, CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "action", CURLFORM_COPYCONTENTS, "upload", CURLFORM_END);

  curl = curl_easy_init();
  headerlist = curl_slist_append(headerlist, buf);
  if(curl) {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.myhost.com/upload/upload.php");
    if ( (argc == 2) && (!strcmp(argv[1], "noexpectheader")) )
      curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headerlist);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPPOST, formpost);

    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    if(res != CURLE_OK)
      fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
              curl_easy_strerror(res));

    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

    curl_formfree(formpost);
    curl_slist_free_all (headerlist);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Tried to add in the HEADER as "Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel" but is not right, I get:

```
Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel
```

in the headers but I need to have:

```
------WebbbbFormBoundaryXaI1UTNwqAyKWvLT
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="importfile"; filename="document.csv"
Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel
```

instead I get:

```
------WebbbbFormBoundaryXaI1UTNwqAyKWvLT
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="importfile"; filename="document.csv"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
```

Thanks for help guys, answer is:

```
curl_formadd(&formpost, &lastptr, CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "importfile", CURLFORM_FILE, "document.csv", CURLFORM_CONTENTTYPE, "application/vnd.ms-excel", CURLFORM_END);
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the [`Accept`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.1) header?

Comment: Yes I did, but is set in the header and I need in the POST data to be set.

Comment: You can override the default POST Content-Type:  header by setting your own with CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for [curl_formadd](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_formadd.html)'s option [CURLFORM_CONTENTTYPE](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_formadd.html#CURLFORMCONTENTTYPE).